# Помогите составить регулярное выражение для вытакскивания даты из текста

Tags: python

Есть следующий текст:

**12.03.19** в 10:00 (6 дн.) какой-то другой текст о чём-то очень интересном.

**Задача:**

Нужно что-бы регулярное выражение вытаскивало из текста фрагмент выделенный в примере **жирным**. (дата может быть любой)

Comment: [(?:\d{2}\.){2}\d{2}](https://regex101.com/r/wMBXsZ/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что если использовать функцию split()

```
 text.split(" ")[0]
```

Comment: да, думаю подаёт.